# Disable Colour Filters in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Since Windows 10 1709 there is a hotkey for turn on / off Colour Filter. And that hotkey is Ctrl+Win+C.
There is any option to disable that "feature" and use that hotkey in another software?

UPD: I used following AutoHotKey script to remap Ctrl+Win+C to my Play/Pause

```
^#C::
   Send {Media_Play_Pause}
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 doesn't allow you to change the system default hotkeys. The only way around this is to intercept the keys and make them do something else. You can do this using a tool called [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

I haven't used this tool for a while so I can't give you detailed instructions but you can find a tutorial and some help [on their website](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I used following [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to remap `Ctrl+Win+C` to `Play/Pause`, and it helped.

```
^#C::
   Send {Media_Play_Pause}
Return
```